# How to list files with numbers in their name and retrieve the numbers?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am very new to regex, therefore I do imagine this is quite a simple question to answer and must have been asked several times already, but unfortunly I can't find any of those answers.

Given a directory, I need the list of all of its subdirectories whose names respect the pattern "nw=[number].a=[number]", and for every directory I need to retrieve those numbers and do a few things based on those. Some of these directories are nw=82.a=40, nw=100.a=9, ecc.

My guess to accomplish this would be

```
#! /bin/bash

cd $mydir
for dir in `ls | grep nw=[:digit:]+.a=[:digit:]`: do
    retrieve the numbers
    a few things
done
```

Why doesn't it work, and how could I retrieve the numbers?

Thank you in advance,
        Ferdinando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -e '@a=`ls`;m/nw=(\d+)\.a=(\d+)(?{print"$1\t$2\n"})/ for@a'
```

Enjoy.

Call the terminal's ls command and store the list in the array @a.

```
@a=`ls`;
```

looking for match

```
m/
```

nw=(digits that I capture in $1).a=(digits that I capture in $2)

```
nw=(\d+)\.a=(\d+)
```

start evaluation of code from within a pattern

```
(?{
```

print first number,tab, second number, newline

```
print"$1\t$2\n"})
```

end matching pattern group

```
/
```

perform this match attempt with embedded code on each filename (with newlines still appended) in array @a

```
for@a
```

Yes, that was cryptic.

Comment: Thank you much, altough this is a bit cryptical to me right now.
Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: This is not a good answer for someone "very new to regex", as it introduces a whole new language to the discussion; uses advanced, little-used regex features; makes everything crammed together to save a few characters; and offers no explanation.

Comment: Thank you much, now that you explained it is perfect for what i need :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some corrections on your grep command:

```
grep -E 'nw=[[:digit:]]+\.a=[[:digit:]]+'
```

1. Use the "-E" flag so you can use an extended regex, which includes the '+' operator, for example.
2. Use double square brackets
3. Escape the period, otherwise it will be used as an operator to match any character
4. A final '+' was missing from the end, not entirely necessary since grep will match more general cases, but it probably represents better your path names
5. It is probably good practice to place your regex between quotes (in this case, single quotes will do)

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Single quotes are generally the best choice.  Use double quotes if you must substitute a shell variable into the regex, but be cautious.

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse `ls`. Use `find` instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*nw=[0-9]+\.a=[0-9]+.*' | while IFS= read -r dir
do
    echo "Found directory: $dir"
    if [[ "$dir" =~ nw=([0-9]+)\.a=([0-9]+) ]]
    then
        echo "numbers are ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} and ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done
```